# Check if a youtube movie is already reindexed

Tags: youtube, indexing, youtube-api

Is there any way using youtube API to check if a video is already reindexed in the youtube search index after modyfying one of its tags?
Language is not important right now, but prefered one is Java / Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you update the video with the new tag, following the steps [illustrated here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#update_a_video), video goes into the reindex queue. It will be picked from queue based on the internal logic. As of now, I don't think we have an API to say the status of the index.

If your application has a need to do so, with current available API, you can poll for the video and retrieve the tags, check if your tag modification is available (temporary solution).

Comment: Are you sure, that after I poll for the video, I get the one with updated tags only when it gets reindexed?

Comment: once it gets reindexed, it will be having the new attributes associated with it. You can retrieve your uploads using - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#retrieve_my_uploads

Answer (score -1):

After you have completed upload you can  use processingDetails  via a [youtube.videos.list() call.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Example:

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=processingDetails&id=P41w1KkcP5w&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Response:

> 200 OK
>
> - Show headers -    {  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",  "etag": "\"gMjDJfS6nsym0T-NKCXALC_u_rM/Q2AsW8DSmKUN3ErB0YUS15N7t_o\"", 
>     "pageInfo": {   "totalResults": 1,   "resultsPerPage": 1  },  "items":
>     [   {
>
>   "kind": "youtube#video",    "etag":
>     "\"gMjDJfS6nsym0T-NKCXALC_u_rM/G9iHMnwcFYD3asMQYe-pvgVk0pQ\"",
>     "id": "P41w1KkcP5w",    "processingDetails": {
>     **"processingStatus": "terminated"**    }   }  ] }

Comment: According to api documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#processingDetails.processingStatus processingDetails contains only the information about upload status which can be polled in order to track the progress. Field processingStatus has possible values: failed, processing, succeeded or terminated. Terminated means only that processing information is no longer available and does not say anything about refreshing YouTube search index after changed tags for already uploaded video.